Unable to connect to service principal/keyvault
I'm running a pwsh script that is supposed to connect to mggraph using a service principal. This will ultimately be used in powershellcore on linux. I've found that I need to do Connect-AzAccount -Identity first but no matter how I format it I get "WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant 'organizations' with error 'ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.'
Connect-AzAccount: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint."
Later on in the script when I try to connect to mggraph using :Connect-MgGraph -ClientId $clientId -TenantId $tenantId -Credential $psCredential" I get
"Connect-MgGraph: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided."
This is the full bit I'm working with to try to connect. I'm pulling specific user data as a CSV report.
# Define the necessary variables
$ClientId = "clientID"
$TenantId = "tenantID"
$KVName = "kv-name"
$secretName = "secretname"
$subscriptionid = "subscription"
Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscriptionid -tenant $tenantId
# Authenticate to Azure using Managed Identity (assuming it's enabled)
Connect-AzAccount -Identity 
# Retrieve the secret (service principal password) from Azure Key Vault
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $kvName -Name $secretName

# Convert the secret value to a secure string
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $secret.SecretValue -AsPlainText -Force

# Create a PSCredential object for the service principal using the retrieved secret
$psCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($clientId, $securePassword)

# Connect to Microsoft Graph using the service principal credentials
Connect-MgGraph -ClientId $clientId -TenantId $tenantId -Credential $psCredential

Connect-MgGraph -clientId "$clientid" -TenantId "$tenantid" -Credential $psCredential`

I've tried changing the variables to see if that's the issue. Tried changing Connect-AzAccount -Identity to Connect-AzAccount -Identity "ServicePrinciplaName". I've ran verbose on it and got the same. I've tried with -devicecode if its trying to be interactive. I've found information that Update-AzConfig -EnableLoginByWam $false might work but got the same issue. I've tried calling the vault url.
